# Sincronizar columnas de diferentes tablas (trigger)

Tags: mysql, netbeans, mysql-workbench, trigger

tengo que sincronizar columnas de diferentes tablas. Ya vi 200 tutoriales pero aun no puedo hacerlo:

Lo que se deja en la columna ent_ubi de la tabla entrada, tiene que pasar a la tabla inventario columna inv_ubi. Es un proyecto personal de control de inventario.
Primero se ingresa la ubicación de entrada (ent_ubi) y la info que aparecería ahí debería enviarse a inv_ubi.

Me podrán dar una mano formulando el trigger o hacer una descripción de algo similar?

[image: Entrada]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lee de nuevo tu enunciado. En una parte dices que la información entra en int_ubi y luego que parte en ent_ubi

Comment: Tenés razon, mil gracias. Ya corregí lo que quería poner.

Comment: Pero.. cual seria el problema.. no sabes hacer un trigger?

Comment: Claro, no entiendo como hacer un trigger.